# Why is the absolute value of the side in this problem taken to find theta?

Tags: vectors

[image]

To find the resultant magnitude and its direction (theta) in this problem, one must perform the following procedure:

[image]

However, my point of confusion is why they took the absolute value of Rx at the end of the problem when they found the angle 21.3? In other vector problems, the negative sign is **NOT** removed from any of the components before finding R (using arctan). So why was the negative sign removed from Rx = -89.3 this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking $\phi = \tan^{-1}\left( R_y / R_x \right)$ gives the angle between the vector and the $x$-axis, on the interval $[-90^\circ,90^\circ]$, with positive angles in the upper-right quadrant.  Your favorite implementation of $\tan^{-1}$ might return angles on the interval $[0^\circ, 180^\circ)$ instead.

In the problem, however, your $\theta$ is drawn to suggest a small positive angle *with the y-axis* corresponds to a resultant in the upper-left quadrant.  To get an angle with the positive $y$-axis, you have to make two changes:

1. Reverse the coordinates from what's usual, $|\theta| = \left|\tan^{-1}\frac{R_x}{R_y}\right|$ (not $\frac{R_y}{R_x}$)
2. Fudge the sign so that positive $\theta$ points as shown.